# object cannot be nil for Facebook login in IOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, runtime-error

I'm attempting to integrate Facebook compatibility into my game to be able to share your score at the end of gameplay.

I have followed all the steps outlined on Facebook's documentation but i can't seem to find the cause for this error or the object that is set to nil.

When I press the login button that is generated from the following code:

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

I receive this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: client_id)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183fc659c 0x1946cc0e4 0x183eb11f8 0x1000b690c 0x1000b6d18 0x1000b6cc4 0x1000b5b8c 0x1000b2794 0x1887a9418 0x18879252c 0x1887a8db4 0x1887a8a40 0x1887a1f94 0x18877568c 0x188a1460c 0x188773bf4 0x183f7e9ec 0x183f7dc90 0x183f7bd40 0x183ea90a4 0x18d04b5a4 0x1887daaa4 0x1000a3f0c 0x194d3aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thank you!

EDIT:

```
0   Eggs                                0x00000001000e1994 -[GameViewController viewDidLoad] + 920
1   UIKit                               0x0000000188775184 <redacted> + 692
2   UIKit                               0x0000000188774e94 <redacted> + 32
3   UIKit                               0x000000018877b55c <redacted> + 72
4   UIKit                               0x0000000188778cdc <redacted> + 260
5   UIKit                               0x00000001887e9d24 <redacted> + 56
6   UIKit                               0x00000001889fd890 <redacted> + 2804
7   UIKit                               0x00000001889ffe08 <redacted> + 1480
8   UIKit                               0x00000001889fe4a0 <redacted> + 184
9   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000018c23562c <redacted> + 28
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183f7ea28 <redacted> + 20
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183f7db30 <redacted> + 312
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183f7c154 <redacted> + 1756
13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000183ea90a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
14  UIKit                               0x00000001887dfaac <redacted> + 552
15  UIKit                               0x00000001887daaa4 UIApplicationMain + 1488
16  Eggs                                0x00000001000e7efc main + 116
17  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000194d3aa08 <redacted> + 4
```

Comment: had you check your code with breakpoint that on which line exactly error comes

Comment: could you post the stack trace at the moment of the break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I figured it out by checking the info.plist. I would recommend to double check your spellings.  It needs to be FacebookAppID, and I put it as FacebookID. When I fixed the typo, it runs fine. However it is possible that you encounter the problem differently.

Comment: You still have typo error :) Not FackbookAppID, it should be FacebookAppID

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think those 3 lines caused the error. It would be great if you provide, few more coding lines. Please use follow code for latest Facebook integration.

```
   -(void)viewDidLoad{
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];

    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(profileUpdated:) name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification object:nil];

     }
-(void)profileUpdated:(NSNotification *) notification{
    NSLog(@"User name: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].name);
    NSLog(@"User ID: %@",[FBSDKProfile currentProfile].userID);
}

- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error{

}
- (void)loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{

}
```

Comment: Sivajee, I did all this and more but somehow I am unable to see my button at all in my view, any idea why this might be going totally wrong for me?

Comment: Did you try adding frame to loginButton?

Comment: I did, and still the problem persisted till later. Then I stopped adding my button to self.scrollview subview and added to my self.view and it worked but If i added it to my scrollview it wasn't visible at all. Dont understand why though. Anyhow, thank you for getting back to me :)